# Langchain throwing parsing response error with human tool

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, large-language-model

I am trying to use langchain agent to generate a one month interview plan for a software engineer. Expectation is that agent should ask user few questions and generate a plan.

```
import os
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentType

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-"    

def _handle_error(error) -> str:
    return str(error)[:50]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0)
    tools = load_tools(
        ["human"],
        llm=llm,
    )
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
    agent_chain = initialize_agent(
        tools,
        llm,
        agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        verbose=True,
        memory=memory,
        max_iterations=3,
        handle_parsing_errors=_handle_error
    )

    agent_chain.run(
        "I want you to create a one-month interview preparation plan with the help of OpenAI by understanding my current skill level. Ask questions to user and get the answers and use them to generate plan")
```

It is throwing the following error:
[image]

Expecting it to ask some questions, as shown in the following chatGPT screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
# agent_chain.run(
#     "I want you to create a one-month interview preparation plan with the help of OpenAI by understanding my current skill level. Ask questions to user and get the answers and use them to generate plan")

try:
    response= agent_chain.run("I want you to create a one-month interview preparation plan with the help of OpenAI by understanding my current skill level. Ask questions to user and get the answers and use them to generate plan")
except Exception as e:
    response = str(e)
    if response.startswith("Could not parse LLM output: `"):
        response = response.removeprefix("Could not parse LLM output: `").removesuffix("`")
        print(response)
```

Output -
[image]

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: can you explain how this may help? i may get to see your suggestion

Comment: after code change are you still getting same error, I attached screenshot of output for same program..

Comment: i am getting the error. Can you share entire code including llm model used. not sure if there is any difference at that level

Comment: ohh at my end slight change because of some environment variables.  #llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0)
    deployment_name =  "text-davinci-003"
    llm = AzureOpenAI(deployment_name=deployment_name, temperature=0)

Comment: i see you are using AzuerOpenAI. does this mean ChatOpenAI has issue in responding in correct way? correct me if my understanding is incorrect

Comment: no AzureOpenIA and ChatOpenAI both throws error and this is known issue https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/1358.. this workaround helps

Comment: is there anything i am missing. getting same error even after making changes you suggested. can you please review code here: https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/393449cb10b8a46c3c27cb26b9bda614

Comment: other option would be going with AzureOpeAI, the LLM is not able to produce output based on the skills that we provide as input. Or you can take totally different approach excluding human agent..